# SSLv3 not supported by this version of OpenSSL

Tags: apache, web, openssl

I am running a Qualys PCI compliant tool and I see many fixes in the report, one of them tells me to update the file default-ssl.conf and set the line SSLProtocol -ALL ***+SSLv3*** +TLSv1 as follows. The problem is that Apache does not start, the journalctl -xe command sends me this message : SSLv3 not supported by this version of OpenSSL.

The Apache version is : Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu).
The openssl version : OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017

The Apache version is one of the latest so does the Openssl, any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks,

jm

Comment: Technically, OpenSSL 1.1.0g should be able to support SSLv3 (NOT RECOMMENDED). But if you're using an already compiled package, it has most probably be compiled without the support of SSLv3. The only way I can see would be to download both the source of OpenSSL and Apache, recompile OpenSSL with the SSLv3 support and recompile Apache/mod_ssl against that newly compiled OpenSSL librairies. But then again, can't see why you want to enable SSLv3.